# Retrieve in SQL between two range of dates

Tags: sql

I have a set of records in the database as follows:

```
Id  Name      ExecutedFrom               ExecutedTo              Type
1   Cholo     2020-06-02 15:14:51.000    2020-06-03 15:14:51.000  A
2   Bacha     2020-06-04 15:14:51.000    2020-06-05 15:14:51.000  B
3   Chatwa    2020-06-04 15:14:51.000    2020-06-05 15:14:51.000  C
```

How can I retrieve all records between the previous and the current day in SQL?  Like, in this case I will pass two parameters namely `DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)` as ExecutedFrom and `DateTime.UtcNow`  as ExecuteTo as parameter, so it should return me the two records with Id 2 and 3. How can I achieve that in SQL? Please help.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can do something like this:

```
select * from mytable 
where   ExecutedFrom >= dateadd(DAY, -1, getdate()) 
AND dateadd(DAY, 1, getdate()) <= ExecutedTo;
```